Convert an ellipse-like shape in QGIS into an ellipse with the correct angle
I want to convert an ellipse-like polygon into an ellipse. In QGIS, I use Oriented minimum bounding box to generate the bounding box and then in the following code to generate the ellipse within it:
make_ellipse
    (centroid($geometry),
            "height"/2,
            "width"/2 ,
            "angle"
            )


Green is the oriented minimum bounding box. Red line is the geometry generated from the code.
Now, I want to use Geometry by Expression to automate this process based on the code. But both of the provided code examples mentioned in this article can't produce the correct angles.

make_ellipse(
    centroid($geometry),
    bounds_width($geometry)/2,
    bounds_height($geometry)/2,
    main_angle($geometry),
    45
    )

make_ellipse(
    centroid($geometry),
    bounds_width($geometry)/2,
    bounds_height($geometry)/2,
    main_angle(
        make_line(
            centroid($geometry),
            closest_point(centroid($geometry),$geometry)
            )
        )-90,
    45
    )

How do I fix the code to get the ellipse with the correct angle?
UPDATE:

Green is the Oriented minimum bounding box.
Red line is generated from Gabriel De Luca's code.

Do you have a sample of data to test with ?

looks like in the presented examples, the bounds_width parts actually take the standard bounding boxes, not the oriented ones.  I tried a bit without finding a well suited solution quickly

The width and height should be calculated from the unrotated, straightened geometry.
You should therefore rotate the geometry by the negative main angle, before taking its height and width, from which to derive the length of the ellipse's axes.
with_variable('angle',
 main_angle(@geometry),
with_variable('unrotated',
 rotate(@geometry, -@angle),
make_ellipse(
 centroid(oriented_bbox(@geometry)),
 bounds_height(@unrotated)/2,
 bounds_width(@unrotated)/2,
 @angle)
))


Thank you, the results from your code are very close to what I need. Just need  to change @geometry to $geometry.
However, it seems that I cannot use the Field Calculator script to produce an ellipse inside the oriented minimum bounding box.
Is this because the Field Calculator doesn't have a function for oriented minimum bounding boxes?
I have already updated the result images on my original question.

Do you mean Field Calculator or Geometry by expression? Besides this you might want to use the Bounding box's centroid rather than the Geometry's centroid. Oriented BBox is oriented_bbox($geometry), you therefore might want to try to replace Gabriel's formula with centroid(oriented_bbox($geometry)) for the centroid part.

Thanks for the suggestion, now this code works perfectly to achieve my desired result - cheers!

Thanks @Kasper. - Updated the center of the ellipse to the centroid of the oriented minimum bounding box instead of the centroid of the original geometry. - Keep the @geometry variable as is, since the use of $geometry is deprecated since QGIS 3.34. https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry

Thank you for reminding me about the issue with QGIS versions and $geometry @geometry. I was using version 3.22, which gave me NULL results. Switching to 3.40 solved the problem, Thank you again!
